# Hashicorp vault PKI minimum key size

Tags: key, size, pki, hashicorp-vault

I am using Hashicorp vault PKI as a CA to issue RSA based certificates.
The produced keys are 2048 bits long. How do I set the minimum key size to 4096?

Comment: // , Did you look at the HashiCorp docs before posting?

Answer (score 2):

In the "Generate intermediate" request you can specify the number of bits of the certificates with the parameter "key_bits". Setting this parameter to 4096 should set the minimum key size.

Path to use:

```
POST    /pki/intermediate/generate/:type    200 application/json
```

Parameter to set:

```
key_bits (int: 2048) – Specifies the number of bits to use. This must be changed to a valid value if the key_type is ec.
```

Full documentation here:
https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/pki/index.html#generate-intermediate

Comment: // , Here's a more specific link to the `key_bits` part: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/pki/index.html#key_bits Thanks for reading the documentation for us